# Get the text fragment part of current URL from window.location

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, browser

I wanted to have a custom layout for anyone visitsing my website with [text fragment](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment) link.

eg. `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cat&oldid=916388819#:~:text=Claws-,Like%20almost,the%20Felidae%2C,-cats`

Here the part after `:~:` will be the text fragment. I wanted to get that part.

I have tried `window.location.href` and `window.location.hash`. But
`window.location.href` returns just the url without `text fragment` while `window.location.hash` returns an empty string.

To replicate this visit this `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cat&oldid=916388819#:~:text=Claws-,Like%20almost,the%20Felidae%2C,-cats` by copying and pasting it to new tab, and try getting the text fragment from `window.location` (markdown link seems to have problem with text fragment).

So is there any other way to get the text fragment part in address bar ?

Comment: .hash will contain it

Comment: I have tried in both firefox and chrome. It doesn't seems to contain. `window.location.hash` just returns an empty string. Does it work for you `window.location.hash` on that wikipedia page ?

Comment: [yes](http://imgur.com/SOBZJlel.png), how are you executing it?

Comment: It has the hash but I don't know why the text fragments are not working when clicking from the markdown link directly. When clicking on the markdown link it open wikipedia but also doesn't select the text which text fragments are for. So please open the link by copy pasting `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cat&oldid=916388819#:~:text=Claws-,Like%20almost,the%20Felidae%2C,-cats` from here and then try getting hash

Comment: [empty hash string](https://imgur.com/U2Lvgix)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone your fragment from your screenshot was URL escaped and not interpreted by the browser as a text fragment.

No, in Chrome, `.hash` *does not* contain text fragment as of recent versions.  Firefox is fine.  

I would consider this a breaking change, and Chrome should fix window.location.hash to give back what it did before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the text fragment via `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].name` (you can run a regular expression to get the actual value, like `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].name.split('#:~:text=')[1]` [but you probably want to make this more forgiving and error-resistent]).

Comment: Using `performance` here is a pretty big hack/work around.  Chrome should fix `window.location.hash` to behave as it did before.  The whole of uninterpreted hash should be given.

Comment: I agree in general. Read and track the conversation on the [spec issue](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment/issues/128) for some background on this.

Answer (score 4):

#### It's currently different based on browser.

## Firefox

`window.location.href` and `window.location.hash` work as they have worked since the dawn of Javascript and behave exactly as you would expect.

## Chrome

Recent
changes have modified fragment behavior.  **Chrome will now remove parts of the URL if `:~:` appears in the URL.**

As @DenverCoder9 pointed out, the only guaranteed way to get the whole URL, what should be a simple task, is now only accomplishable in Chrome via the `performance` API, `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].name`.  This task that used to be accomplishable via `window.location.href`, `window.location.hash`, and `document.URL` is no longer possible without this gotcha.

We hope Chrome's new behavior, requiring `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].name` compared to `window.location.href`, is reverted back.  This new behavior of "removing parts of the URL" is unprecedented and we consider it harmful.

Worse, if using protocol `file://`, there is no way to get the URL as `performance` will not report the URL.

Related, see issues:

- https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment/issues/193
- https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment/issues/74#issuecomment-1215767738

Keywords: "text fragments", "fragment directives"